# How do I hide a file with AutoIt v3?

Tags: autoit

Using AutoIt v3, I need to copy a file and have the resulting file (a .dll) be hidden.

I tried FileCopy & FileInstall orders but they just make the file visible and not hidden after execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [`FileCopy()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileCopy.htm) and [`FileInstall()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileInstall.htm) have no arguments to set file attributes (You can see this in the function reference).

You need to move/copy the file to the intended location and then set the file attributes. [`FileSetAttrib()`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileSetAttrib.htm) serves just that purpose.

```
FileCopy("nefarious.dll", "/path/to/innocent_looking.dll")
FileSetAttrib("/path/to/innocent_looking.dll", "+H")
```

Comment: btw i used FileInstall()...
Because in FileCopy() order...my AutoIt file needed to be with dll file or it will not copy & hide it even after compiling the script